# Element.classList Cannot read property 'toggle'

Tags: javascript, string, addition

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined at HTMLTableCellElement.toto

Can someone help?

```
var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('organisation');
var numComments = comments.length;

function toto(e){
    /*this.style.cssText='background-color:white';*/
    comments.classList.toggle('.maClasse');
}

for (var i = 0; i < numComments; i += 1) {
    comments[i].addEventListener('click', toto, false);
}
```

Comment: sorry ! i got the answer !

Comment: var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('organisation');
  var numComments = comments.length;

  //function toto(e){
   //this.style.cssText='background-color:white';
   //comments.classList.toggle('.maClasse')
   function myFunction() {
    this.classList.toggle("maClasse");
};
  //}
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numComments; i += 1) {
   comments[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
  }

Comment: yes is javascript, but it's okay i find the solution :) and i edit also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good!

```
var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('organisation');
var numComments = comments.length;

//function toto(e){
    //this.style.cssText='background-color:white';
    //comments.classList.toggle('.maClasse')
    function myFunction() {
        this.classList.toggle("maClasse");
    };
//}

for (var i = 0; i < numComments; i += 1) {
    comments[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```